# CSS code inside my media query is ignored

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to pad a `<p>` left only at a certain screen size. I have the following CSS and HTML:

```css
float-left-icon {
    padding-left: inherit;  
}

@media only screen and ( max-width : 991px) {
    float-left-icon{
        padding-left: 30px;   
    }
}
```

```html
<p class="float-left-icon" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" >Test</a>
</p>
```

My problem is that the `float-left-icon` class isn't even showing up in the developer tools when I debug it in the browser... So it isn't even firing.

Can someone please advice what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Correct code :

You need to add a `.` character in front of your CSS selectors :

```css
.float-left-icon {
    padding-left: inherit;  
}

@media only screen and ( max-width : 991px) {
    .float-left-icon{
        padding-left: 30px;   
    }
}
```

```html
<p class="float-left-icon" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" >Test</a>
</p>
```

---

### Explanation :

In CSS, class names start with a `.`, id names start with a `#` and tag names start don't need a special character in front.

Take the following example :

```css
.span {
   color : red;
}
#span {
   color : green;
}
span {
   color : blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="span">Meep meep</p>
<p id="span">Meep meep</p>
<span>Vrooooom</span>
```

See the [**W3Schools documentation**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more details on how to use CSS selectors.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.` to denote a class in CSS.

Change `float-left-icon` in your CSS to `.float-left-icon`

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot a dot (`.`) character:

```
.float-left-icon {
    padding-left: inherit;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .float-left-icon {
        padding-left: 30px;         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes need to be preceeded by a `.`, IDs by `#` and so on. So change your rules to:

```
.float-left-icon{
    padding-left: inherit;      
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 991px)
{
    .float-left-icon {
        padding-left: 30px;         
    }
}
```

If you'll only be using this rule to pad `<p>`'s you can make it more specific by changing your rule to `p.float-left-icon`.

Answer (score 0):

Because CSS for `float-left-icon` isn't referring `class`. It should be preceeded with `.`

```
.float-left-icon{
        padding-left: inherit;      
 }
 @media only screen and ( max-width : 991px)
 {
     .float-left-icon{
            padding-left: 30px;         
     }
 }
```